# Load denied by X-Frame-Options Customer Community

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, customer-community, single-sign-on, iframe

I am embedding a Visualforce page as a iframe inside a Lightning component. When I log in as a customer community user using SSO, I get the "Load denied by X-Frame-Options" error. However, if I log in as the customer community user through the Contact record page, I do not get this error. Is there a difference between the two login sessions? More importantly, how do I get my embedded Visualforce page to work in Customer Community

Comment: I have seen this issue when I log in but in the builder only because the URL is different but never in the actual community while loggin in as a user or via contact unless the top URL is different. What is the top URL in your case and what if the iframe policy for the site?

Comment: Yes, the builder makes sense since the actual logged in user is an internal user. The top URL is the SFDC generated community URL